# how to config variables like colors、paddings,、margins and more use scss with primeng in project?

Tags: primeng

how to config variables like colors、paddings,、margins and more use scss with primeng in  project?

I want to change the styles of some components with scss, but not found the methold,  Is there any other solution? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no scss support for free themes. You need to buy primeng designer licence to design your own theme in scss.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/6491